# Store the first byte of a string into a another string: algorithm of LZW Compression

Tags: c, string

If `s` is a string (say `"thisisthe"`), how do I store the first byte into a another string `s2`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s[]="thisisthe"; 
    char s1=s[0]; // Store the first byte of s as a char.
    char s2[]=s[1]; // store the second byte of s as a string.
    printf("%s\n",s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you avoid CUBITAL BOLD characters? thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`s2` is a character, not a string.
Change

```
printf("%s\n", s2);
```

to

```
printf("%c\n", s2);
```

If you want `s2` to be a string you should first declare it:

```
char s2[2];
s2[0] = s[1];
s2[1] = '\0';  //the terminating character
```

Comment: sorry i want to make


'char s2[]=s[1];'

Comment: i need to store s2 as a string hold one char

Comment: "you should first declare it:" to be specific, it shall be "define it"

Answer (score 2):

In C, a string it an array of characters terminated by a NUL.

```
char s2[2];
s2[0] = s[1];
s2[1] = '\0';
```

But maybe you just want

```
char c2 = s[1]; 
printf("%c\n", c2);
```

Comment: `s2[0] = s2[1];` typo?